# dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: causing memory crash

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, ios8

So I'm working on an app, and from a base view I fire up a login view if I don't have a username stored in the app defaults.

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if !defaults.objectForKey("username") {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.navigationController.tabBarController.performSegueWithIdentifier("Login", sender: self)
    })
}
```

The code fires a "Present Modally" (iOS 8) segue in my storyboard that presents a form sheet with default animation.

The view that it creates has various subviews arranged using AutoLayout.

Now, later in my code (upon checking the sign in is valid and updating the defaults) I dismiss the login view.

```
defaults.setObject(signInData["username"], forKey: "username")
defaults.setObject(signInData["password"], forKey: "password")
defaults.synchronize()
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
})
```

And here I get a crash in the app. Specifically, the error message (when zombie objects are enabled) is

```
-[_UILayoutGuide superview]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fb3cc93bdb0
```

where UILayoutGuide is clearly AutoLayout related.

Now it appears that my view is getting deallocated upon being dismissed, but there's a pointer to it that is retained despite that. I'm not sure how to fix it though, since it's not in any code I wrote (I think) but in the AutoLayout system itself.

Comment: Could you add a stack trace at the moment of the crash, please?

Answer (score 0):

_UILayoutGuide is the class of the object, and 0x7fb3cc93bdb0 is the object's old RAM location (now the location of the zombie object.)  "superview" is the message being sent to the zombie.

Since you posted before Beta-2 was released, did one of the updates fix your problem?

Answer (score -1):

I faced this problem , my app got crash because  some constraints of views were still active after  pop(or dismiss) view controller , following was the error code . After debugging some time I found that views Constraints were  hugged to Bottom or Top View Layouts , which was the main reason of crash , so I have changed that constraint(From layout view to Parent View ) to parent View  see the snapshot . [image]

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal. constraint: view:>'